# Could I import all the vue.js components from a folder?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In my Nuxt project I have a folder called pages and in that folder I have folders that have the same name as pages. So I have a index folder in components/pages. I put all the subsections of a page in that folder. Could I import all the modules from that folder into my index page in one import line?

Comment: Have you looked to the 'import-glob' npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob ?

Comment: No, i'll take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with help of 'import-glob' npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob . According to the docs:

> ES6 import with glob patterns (preloader for Webpack)
>
> Expands globbing patterns for ES6 import statements.

```
import modules from "./foo/**/*.js";
```

> Expands into

```
import * as module0 from "./foo/1.js";
import * as module1 from "./foo/bar/2.js";
import * as module2 from "./foo/bar/3.js";

modules = [module0, module1, module2]
```